# How to use views to display different information sources

Tags: views

On my home page I want to have a series of 'blocks'. Here is a graphic illustrating what I would like to achieve

[image: views prototype]

The first two would be updated with the latest two blog post, the third would be the Facebook feed iframe, then the last three would be images promoting a different page on the site via a link.

I currently have each of these blocks prepared as separate views. Each of these are hard-coded into page.tpl with views_embed_view(). This isn't ideal as I want to be able to easily add and remove these boxes from within the Drupal admin.

How do I create a 'master view' to display on the front page that will hold these separate views?

Comment: are you using Context module?

Comment: No, I'm quite new to Drupal, I'll check it out

Comment: are you using custom theme or contributed one?

Comment: I think the best would be a using [context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module or [Page manager](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) provided in the ctools package.

Comment: This sounds like a job for [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are many ways to achieve the same result in Drupal. In the end I went for 'Context'. By using 'Panels', it does not appear to be flexible enough to easily add extra blocks when needed.

- Set the condition to `<front>`
- In reaction add `blocks`
- Then drop in all the required views into `content`